# How to check open ports using powershell?

Tags: powershell, port, network-scan

I would like to write a script to check radom IP or hostname to see if ports are open. Here is what I have so far. The scripts name is checkports.

```
foreach ($xhost in $computername){
    Write-Host $xhost
    foreach ($port in $ports) {
        $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient            
        $Connection = $Socket.BeginConnect($xhost,$port,$null,$null) 

        $Connection.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000,$false) | out-null

        if ($Connection -eq $true)
            { write-host = "$xhost port $port is open" }
        else
            { write-host = "port $port is closed" }      

        $Socket.EndConnect($Connection)
        $Socket.Close()
   }
}
```

I would like to input values in the following way:
.\checkport '192.186.1.5' 
or
'192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.105', 192.168.1.110' | checkport

It doesn't seem to be reading IP address or displaying results.

I was wondering if anyone could point out there could show me what I am doing wrong in with this script?

Comment: [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/02/use-powershell-for-network-host-and-port-discovery-sweeps.aspx) and [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-TSPingSweep-b71f1b9b) may be of some help.

Comment: Can you show your param block for the script?

Comment: 1. The return value from `WaitOne` will tell you if the wait completed or timed out: but you are throwing it away. 2. Why not use the blocking `Socket.Connect` given you are going to block?

Comment: Here is a gist with a powershell script which checks for open ports https://gist.github.com/dhcgn/44acdddbaea24d2f367d85a00389368c

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to use the 'Test-Port' function from Boe Prox for similar scan/ reporting functions, the code is available on PoshCode:

http://poshcode.org/2514

When I needed to test ports for Directory health, I built a csv with 'port' and 'protocol' columns, then added the port number/ protocol for each port to check. This was used in the following script:

```
. .\test-port.ps1

$computersToCheck = get-content .\computers.txt
$portList = Import-CSV .\portList.csv

foreach($entry in $portList)
{
    $testPortParams = @{
        port = $($entry.port)
    }   
    if( $($entry.protocol) -eq "tcp")
    { $testPortParams += @{ TCP = $true } }
    else
    { $testPortParams += @{ UDP = $true } }

    $outLog = "portTest-$($entry.port)-$($entry.protocol).txt"

    $computersToCheck | 
        Test-Port @testPortParams |
        Sort-Object -Property open,name -descending | 
        format-table -auto -outVariable status
    Add-Content -path $outLog -value $status 
}
```

You could certainly build a feeder script to build the range of IP addresses and ports to scan.